# using cluster by to improve hive query performance

Tags: hive, hiveql

how cluster by improves query performance in hive? What are cases when sending same keys to the same mapper improve performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CLUSTER BY` is basically a shortcut for `DISTRIBUTE BY x SORT BY x`, so it usually it does not send records to the same *mapper* as you say, but rather, on the same reducer. Also, usually, it does not speed up the query itself, but it is used to speed up *the queries on the tables produced with it*.

`DISTRIBUTE BY/CLUSTER BY` are used to as logical partitioning. While a traditional partition is saved in one directory, you can also partition by file, so for instance, when you `DISTRIBUTE/CLUSTER BY` in 256 buckets, it will distribute your records by a hash key in 256 files. Of course, this is useful only if your data has a cardinality much bigger than 256 and the key you use to cluster the data is more or less uniformely distributed, so the buckets are roughly the same size. Otherwise bucketing may do more harm than good.

Going back to your question, when is it useful? Similarly as for partitioning, when querying a table created with `CLUSTERED BY x`, when encountering a query that includes a clause `WHERE x = 'myvalue'` , the optimizer will recognize that the clause is on the bucketing key, and of the 256 buckets of the previous example, will only open the one where 'myvalue' is, dramatically reducing the amount of I/O (1/256 in this case).

Another case is joins, if you're joining two tables that are bucketed on the same field, the optimizer can do a 'bucket to bucket' join using o(n) mergesort, since the data is already sorted, instead of doing a shuffle join on the two tables, which is generally o(nlogn). On a very large dataset, that may mean hours instead of days.

Comment: I think you are confusing `CLUSTER BY` with `CLUSTERED_BY` - The former is used to speed up the _query in which it is being used_ , typically with TRANSFORM/map-reduce scripts, while the latter is used to create bucketed tables that will have faster read times if queried on the bucketed column.

Comment: I think you are confusing a typo for confusion. I had forgotten the clustering syntax for DDL is different from DML. You have to use CLUSTER BY when writing into a CLUSTERED BY table. Anyway, thanks for the note, I corrected the typo.